# I am building a nested tree data card using react but I am stuck, my requirement is to solve using react only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-hooks

My goal is to design card as in the picture using react:

The requirements are:

As above picture as reference
In this implementation,
a feature's sub-features only expand when selected on and only the leaves contribute to the overall
cost.
A feature may have N sub-features. In other words, features and their sub-features are
arbitrarily nested.

So far I could do the expanding part, and to contribute total cost but the task of propagating cost to parent from child in the tree is where I got stuck, Any suggestions could be really helpful.

```
Example:
parent1 (-) (80)  
  child1 (-)  (80)  (when user checks both nested child values sum should)  
    nestedChild1 (50)   (propagate to parents)
    nestedChild2 (30)
parent2 (-) (10)
  child1 (10)

Total should be 80 + 10 = 90 (sum of Parents)
```

[This is codesandbox link for what I have worked on so far:](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-carson-f11z7?file=/src/components/CardItem/CardItem.js)

This is my Card Component:

```
import './Card.css';

import { useState } from 'react';

import { data } from '../../utils/data';
import CardItem from '../CardItem/CardItem';

const Card = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({}); 

  const total = Object.values(price).reduce(
    (total, current) => total + current,
    0
  );

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card__container">
        <h4>
          <b>Subscription Preferences</b>
        </h4>
        <hr />
        <CardItem items={data} setPrice={setPrice} price={price} />
      </div>
      <div className="footer">
        <hr />
        <div className="footer__container">
          <p>Total: ${total} / mo</p>
          <button>Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

This my CardItem Component:

```
import './CardItem.css';

import { useState } from 'react';


const CardItem = ({ items, setPrice, price }) => {
  const [displayChildren, setDisplayChildren] = useState({});

  
  return (
    <div>      
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ul key={item.name}>
          <li>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={(e) => {
                setDisplayChildren({
                  ...displayChildren,
                  [item.id]: !displayChildren[item.id],
                });
                setPrice((price) => ({
                  ...price,
                  [item.id]: e.target.checked ? +e.target.value : 0,
                }));
              }}
              value={item.value ? item.value : 0}
              id={item.id}
            />
            <label htmlFor={item.id}>
              {item.name}
              {item.value ? ` ($${item.value})` : ' (-)'}
            </label>{' '}
            {displayChildren[item.id] && item.items && (
              <CardItem items={item.items} setPrice={setPrice} />
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardItem;
```

Sample Data:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'List title 1',
    items: [
      {
        id: 11,
        name: 'List item 1_1',
        items: [
          {
            id: 111,
            name: 'List item 1_1_1',
            value: 50,
          },
          {
            id: 112,
            name: 'List item 1_1_2',
            value: 35,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 12,
        name: 'List item 1_2',
        value: 30,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'List title 2',
    items: [
      {
        id: 21,
        name: 'List item 2_1',
        value: 15,
      },
      {
        id: 22,
        name: 'List item 2_2',
        value: 35,
      },
    ],
  }
```

Comment: Please note: the norm here is to include the relevant code in the question itself.  Feel free to link to external sites like codesandbox for additional context, but the question should be answerable without it.

Comment: Sure, will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Each depth of options has its own `price` state and there's no way to pass each individual `price` value back up the tree to a parent node for summation.

## Solution

Move the `price` state up/out to the `Card` component and pass the `setPrice` updater function to the `CardItem` to be passed to each level of recursion.

Card.js

```
const Card = () => {
  const [price, setPrice] = useState({}); // <-- lift price state here

  const total = Object.values(price).reduce( // <-- compute derived total
    (total, current) => total + current,
    0
  );

  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card__container">
        <h4>
          <b>Subscription Preferences</b>
        </h4>
        <hr />
        <CardItem items={data} setPrice={setPrice} /> // <-- pass setPrice callback
      </div>
      <div className="footer">
        <hr />
        <div className="footer__container">
          <p>Total: ${total} / mo</p> // <-- render total
          <button>Save</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

CardItem.js

```
const CardItem = ({ items, setPrice }) => { // <-- receive setPrice callback
  const [displayChildren, setDisplayChildren] = useState({});

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <ul key={item.name}>
          <li>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              onChange={(e) => { // <-- change onClick to onChange
                setDisplayChildren({
                  ...displayChildren,
                  [item.id]: !displayChildren[item.id]
                });
                setPrice((price) => ({ // <-- update price on checked or not
                  ...price,
                  [item.id]: e.target.checked ? +e.target.value : 0
                }));
              }}
              value={item.value ? item.value : 0}
              id={item.id}
            />
            <label htmlFor={item.id}>
              {item.name}
              {item.value ? ` ($${item.value})` : " (-)"}
            </label>{" "}
            {displayChildren[item.id] && item.items && (
              <CardItem items={item.items} setPrice={setPrice} /> // <-- pass setPrice
            )}
          </li>
        </ul>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

## Demo

[image: Edit i-am-building-a-nested-tree-data-card-using-react-but-i-am-stuck-my-requirement]

[Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/i-am-building-a-nested-tree-data-card-using-react-but-i-am-stuck-my-requirement-forked-qyjhm?file=/src/components/Card/Card.js) to forked sandbox with computing intermediate subtotals.

Comment: Thank you! for the suggestion. Also, I have a question do you think is it possible to propagate the cost to parent element from child element using the price state based on the individual item keys?

As in like 

Parent element (-)
  child element (-)
    nested child (50) on click 50 should propagate to both child and parent element.

Comment: @nmudd037 Sure. You can either continue the pattern of [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and push the `price` state up the tree more, or pass another *different* callback from the parent for this child `Card` component to invoke and pass data back up the tree.

Comment: @nmudd037 Ah, I answered before I saw your edit. Yeah, you could do that but I should caution you against storing more than a single "source of truth" in amongst your components. In this case you could keep a price state on each node and use an `useEffect` and/or a callback to pass each price value up the tree to be collected at the root for the total computation. This would require more moving parts though.

Comment: Can you help me in elaborating this "In this case you could keep a price state on each node and use an useEffect and/or a callback to pass each price value up the tree to be collected at the root for the total computation. This would require more moving parts though." I tried to solve by changing the keys to store the price and I am thinking to try useRef too but to no avail, I couldn't come up with a solution. Any suggestions or thoughts from you would be really helpful.

Comment: @nmudd037 Sure thing. I don't have time at this very moment, but can elaborate later tonight and update you here.

Comment: Thank you! Meanwhile I will try my best to come up with a solution.